# How to specify a range of grapheme unicode characters?

Tags: css, unicode, utf-8

I would like to use two fonts on a site, one for normal text and one of emojis. And even more specifically only for the country flag emojis. So I have found this way of doing the first part.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: emoji;

  /* Fonts for text outside emoji blocks */
  src: local('Droid Sans Mono'),
       local('Lucida Console'),
       local('Arial Monospaced'),
       local(Arial);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: emoji;

  src: local('Apple Color Emoji'),
       local('Android Emoji'),
       local('Segoe UI'),
       local(EmojiSymbols),
       local(Symbola),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font/Symbola-Emoji.ttf') format('truetype');

  /* Emoji unicode blocks */
  unicode-range: U+1F300-1F5FF, U+1F600-1F64F, U+1F680-1F6FF, U+2600-26FF;
}
```

So the question is how I can specify the range for the flags alone when each flag consists of two unicode characters combined? [The list of flags can be seen here with the corresponding characters.](http://flagpedia.net/emoji)

Comment: The range is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol . So U+1F1E6 to U+1F1FF (which you are not including).